# Перебрать в PHP массив по условию сравнения и вывести данные в таблицу HTML

Tags: php

Прошу Вас о помощи.

Есть массив с данными (ниже привожу вид массива):

```
    Array
    (
        [result] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 38498
                        [IBLOCK_ID] => 36
                        [NAME] => FD 15T-20
                        [IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 
                        [CREATED_BY] => 12
                        [BP_PUBLISHED] => Y
                        [CODE] => 882653861e7b41bca64f0f9a4a03631b
                        [DATE_CREATE] => 22.01.2021 17:07:22
                        [PROPERTY_152] => Array
                            (
                                [162498] => 11012
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_172] => Array
                            (
                                [162500] => 659149
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_516] => Array
                            (
                                [162508] => 01.01.2006
                            )


                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 38500
                        [IBLOCK_ID] => 36
                        [NAME] => GDP18AK
                        [IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 
                        [CREATED_BY] => 12
                        [BP_PUBLISHED] => Y
                        [CODE] => 305f292189d14662ac48f8555278a16c
                        [DATE_CREATE] => 22.01.2021 17:07:23
                        [PROPERTY_152] => Array
                            (
                                [162510] => 11012
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_172] => Array
                            (
                                [162512] => C812R06135N
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_516] => Array
                            (
                                [162520] => 01.01.2015
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 38502
                        [IBLOCK_ID] => 36
                        [NAME] => GDP18AK
                        [IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 
                        [CREATED_BY] => 12
                        [BP_PUBLISHED] => Y
                        [CODE] => 6aaf23342d994bbbb4333537782f5110
                        [DATE_CREATE] => 22.01.2021 17:07:23
                        [PROPERTY_152] => Array
                            (
                                [162522] => 11012
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_516] => Array
                            (
                                [162528] => 01.01.2013
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 38504
                        [IBLOCK_ID] => 36
                        [NAME] => 14RJ-2R
                        [IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 
                        [CREATED_BY] => 12
                        [BP_PUBLISHED] => Y
                        [CODE] => 5e101b442f7a486493bea10a47f9a189
                        [DATE_CREATE] => 22.01.2021 17:07:23
                        [PROPERTY_152] => Array
                            (
                                [162530] => 11012
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_172] => Array
                            (
                                [162532] => 61X836T00714
                            )

                        [PROPERTY_516] => Array
                            (
                                [162540] => 01.01.2006
                            )


                    )
            )
    )
```

Необходимо отсеять данные по значению элемента массива, который сам находится в массиве.

```
[PROPERTY_152] => Array(
[162498] => 11012
)
```

Здесь индекс [162498] каждый раз уникальный, а вот значение может повторяться.

Не могу понять, с какой стороны зайти, чтобы перебрать все данные, сравнивая это значение с переменной и вывести всё это в таблицу.

```
<?php foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td><strong>'.'№'.'</strong></td>'
        .'<td>'.$value['NAME'].'</td>'
        .'<td>'.$array['PROPERTY_152']['0'].'</td>'
        .'<td>'.$value['NAME'].'</td>'
        .'<td>'.$value['NAME'].'</td>'
        .'<td>'.$value['NAME'].'</td>'
        .'<td>'.$value['NAME'].'</td>
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success light sharp" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>';} ?>
```

Выводить нужно только значения в строках таблицы, но как вывести значение из массива внутри массива - не понимаю(

Подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону гуглить.

Comment: почему в foreach задается переменная $value, а внутри цикла используется какая-то $array?

Comment: как называется исходная переменная, в которой лежит вся эта красота неземная?

Comment: @Ипатьев,
Массив получил подобным запросом из Битрикс24

$result = CRest::call(
  'lists.element.get',
  ['IBLOCK_TYPE_ID' => 'lists', 'IBLOCK_ID' => '36']
 );

echo '<pre>';
 print_r($result);

echo '</pre>';
?>

Comment: дальше надо смотреть на схему. в переменной $result есть элемент result. который представляет из себя массив. Вот к нему и надо обращаться. И его перебирать в цикле, обращаясь последовательно к каждому элементу. Перед тем как писать кропотливый HTML надо сначала проверять логику работы. и выводить полученное значение. Чтобы видеть, к каким элементам обращаться

Comment: если вам нужно получить первое значение из вложенного `property_152`  то его можно получить через `current($value['property_152'])`

Comment: А еще немаловероятно что в фильтре можно указать название поля и его значение и получить сразу только нужные записи.

Comment: @u_mulder, это было бы идеально, но я пока не понял, как это делается. Примеров не очень много, учу матчасть и пытаюсь что-то сделать. Эту проблему я решил, перебрав полученный массив, но вот ограничение вывода списочных данных в 50 записей обойти пока не получается(